# How can Pytorch share memory among several processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytorch

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044626/7238787), 'processes have separate memory'. But Pytorch can somehow share memory among several processes, according to this [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/multiprocessing.html): **'Once the tensor/storage is moved to shared_memory (see share_memory_()), it will be possible to send it to other processes without making any copies.'** Why is it possible to share memory among separate memory? Doesn't it sound like a paradox?

Comment: Probably shared to the main process or by using a Manager.dict or similar.

Comment: Perhaps this question is more suitable to ask on PyTorch's own forum https://discuss.pytorch.org/ . You could try asking there.

Comment: Had posted on Pytorch forum;  no one answered me yet :-(

Comment: @jabberwoo where is the pytorch forum with your question?